# Realicé una conexión VB y MYSQL con sentencias para ingresar, modificar, buscar y eliminar.

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Elimino los registros a través un inputbox que toma los valores de N, y en mi script N es auto_increment, lo que trae en consecuencia que, al eliminar deja ese índice sin puesto y cuando ingreso uno nuevo se salta ese. Además, lo indicado sería que cuando elimine un registro el posterior tome su lugar. ¿cómo haría eso? ¿Es una sentencia en el Script o a través del código de VB pero sentencia SQL? Espero puedan ayudarme. Saludos

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que te han calificado negativo en la pregunta por algunas razones:
1. Esta poco claro lo que pides.
2. No se entiende demasiado hacia donde está orientada la pregunta.

Pero a pesar de ello has colocado un trozo de código así que intentaré darte una ayuda.

Si tu punto es que cuando eliminas un registro (tomemos por ej el N= 30), y luego produces un INSERT, el registro nuevo toma el 31 y no el 30.

Bueno, entonces tienes que verificar los índices que genera MySQL. ¿Qué significa esto? Que cuando has creado el "antigüo" N=30 MySQL generó automáticamente un índice y luego cuando lo has eliminado no lo actualizó por ende lo saltó y generó el INSERT con el 31.

Esto puede tener soluciones a nivel MySQL tanto como a nivel código.

Puedo darte una ayuda muy importante para resolverlo a nivel código SQL y que puedes ejecutar desde el VB.

La idea es que modifiquemos la forma en que hacemos el INSERT y no le delegemos la función de decir que ID colocar a la Base sino que lo hagamos nosotros mismos, luego de eliminar el registro N=30 (el código que vos colocaste), supongamos que queremos hacer un INSERT entonces:

```
Mysql = "INSERT INTO Tecnologia('N','Campo') VALUES ((SELECT selected_value + 1 FROM (SELECT MAX(N) AS selected_value FROM `Tecnologia`) AS sub_selected_value),'Agustin');
Com.CommandText = Mysql
Try
com.ExecuteNonQuery()
Catch ex As Exception
End Try
```

Lo importante de esa QUERY se manifiesta en esta sub-consulta:

*(SELECT selected_value + 1 FROM (SELECT MAX(**'CAMPO'**) AS selected_value FROM **'TABLA'**) AS sub_selected_value)*

Que nos devuelve el registro máximo de la tabla + 1 sin fijarse en índices por ende cuando elimines el N=30, el máximo debería ser el 29 y la sub-consulta devolverá nuevamente el N=30.

Saludos

Comment: Muy agradecido, usted entendió totalmente mi pregunta mal planteada. Ya lo intenté y así tal cual, usted dijo, me funcionó. Por cierto, ¿para agrupar el índice? Haciendo la suposición de que, tenía 2 registros y eliminé el primero, cómo haría para que el segundo tome su posición y el tercero que vaya a ingresar lógicamente gracias al código que me presentaste, tomaría el segundo. ¿ahí cómo sería, como ese SELECT MAX o SELECT MIN?

Comment: Con el código tal cual lo publiqué funcionará de manera correcta ya que lo que hace es no dejar que el MySQL coloqué el autonumérico, es decir, que no utilice su propio índice.
Eso significa que con el MAX + 1 siempre se fijará el número más alto y generará un nuevo INSERT con el más alto + 1. Esto siempre que la clave sea *sólo numérica*.

Comment: Eso lo tengo entendido, y sí, tiene toda la razón, funcionó perfectamente. Por cierto, El botón eliminar contiene el DELETE FROM Tabla WHERE N = Número...  en efecto, quedan índices sin uso. ¿cómo haría para que la posición 2 pase a ser 1, la 3 a 2 y la 5 a 3? Gracias de antemano, saludos y bendiciones.

Comment: Exacto bueno esa es limitación que tiene la solución que te di, que los registros eliminados se saltearán por uno más nuevo. Para lograr esto que tu quieres deberías averiguar más como optar por la solución de MySQL de actualizar los índices. A nivel código no he logrado lo que necesitas. En mi caso no utilizo DELETE y no lo había contemplado.

Comment: Como comentario final te diría que si quieres te explayas más sobre para que es tu base y tu intención. Muchisimas veces hay salidas mucho más sencillas de lo que pensamos. Creo, y habiendo leído tu otra pregunta, estás rebuscandote demasiado.

Comment: Realmente no, solamente estoy practicando amigo. No estoy haciendo un proyecto como tal, ¿sí me explico? Muchas gracias por tu consejo, saludos ☺